# How to add a subview to a UITableViewCell

Tags: swift, uitableview, uibutton, uitextfield, subview

I'm making a to-do planner using a table view. When the user presses enter after typing in a task, a button should appear to the left of the task.

The textFieldShouldReturn method in my ViewController class adds the button but not always in the top left corner of the screen. I have it set up like this:

```
func textFieldShouldReturn(_ textField: UITextField) -> Bool {


    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! TextInputTableViewCell

        self.view.addSubview(cell.cellButton) // puts a button in a wrong location, button doesn't respond to any action
        cell.addSubview(cell.cellButton)
        tableViewData.append(textField.text!)
        lastItem = tableViewData.count
        print(tableViewData)
        print(lastItem)

    self.tableView.reloadData() //update row count and array count
    textField.resignFirstResponder()
    return true
```

}

```
self.view.addSubview(cell.cellButton)
```

adds a button to the view but the button doesn't appear in the right place, (i tried moving the location using storyboard, but it doesn't do anything). Plus the button doesn't respond to its appropriate click action, which is declared in the subclass.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! TextInputTableViewCell
    cell.textField.delegate = self
    ...
   return cell
}
```

Any help is appreciated. Let me know if I am not too clear

Answer (score 1):

You're not grabbing the right cell in this line:

```
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell")! as! TextInputTableViewCell
```

You're basically telling the system to just give you a cell. You need to figure out what text field actually returned, and grabbing the cell that contains that text field and then adding your subview to the right cell. The way todo this would be to tag your textFields with the row number.

It works in the first example because you are in cellForRow, so you do have the right cell.

Comment: hmm would you be able to give some code/pseudo-code as to how to do this? I only use one instance of textField for essentially all the rows, which seems to work fine

Comment: Share more code? I think you are incorrect, each cell should have it's own instance of textfield. You may be missing key understandings on how cells are re-used and how they work. Try putting a breakpoint in your delegate method and you'll see that tectfields are different.

Answer (score 0):

Would it be easier if you aligned the button in your .xib or storyboard file, and then kept it hidden until you needed it to appear?